# sysprep error on windows 10: cannot generalize install because Holograms_1.0.0.0_neutral_ cannot be removed but doesn't exist

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, sysprep

I'm running windows 10 Professional, V 1703, build 15063.483.  This is not a virtual machine.

I'm attempting to run `sysprep.exe` to prepare this OS for transplantation into a new chassis.

As shown below, `sysprep` halts with an error about `Package Holograms_1.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image.`.

I have read [this microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2769827/sysprep-fails-after-you-remove-or-update-windows-store-apps-that-inclu) which addresses this error.

That article advises a series of PowerShell commands to forcibly remove the misbehaving act.  However, when i run `Get-AppxPackage -AllUser | Where PublisherId -eq 8wekyb3d8bbwe | Format-List -Property PackageFullName,PackageUserInformation` , **`Holograms_1.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy` does not appear in the list**, so I cannot remove it.

Running `regedit.exe` and searching for the string `Holograms`, i see a few keys in `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ActivatableClasses\CLSID\{9673ECB9-5770-42FB-8E65-841A76DD4DC4}` and `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ActivatableClasses\Package\Holograms_1.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy` and `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Launch\PackageId\Holograms_1.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy`   but  attempts to back up the registry and delete the keys fail on key deletion.

`Holograms` is not listed in my installed programs.

`setuperr.log`:

```
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error                 SYSPRP Package Holograms_1.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image.

2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error                 SYSPRP Failed to remove apps for the current user: 0x80073cf2.

2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error                 SYSPRP Exit code of RemoveAllApps thread was 0x3cf2.

2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error      [0x0f0082] SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Failure occurred while executing 'SysprepGeneralizeValidate' from C:\Windows\System32\AppxSysprep.dll; dwRet = 0x3cf2
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error                 SYSPRP SysprepSession::Validate: Error in validating actions from C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Generalize.xml; dwRet = 0x3cf2
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error                 SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while validating SysprepSession actions; dwRet = 0x3cf2
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error      [0x0f0070] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:An error occurred while running registry sysprep DLLs, halting sysprep execution. dwRet = 0x3cf2
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error      [0x0f00d8] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while pre-validate sysprep generalize internal providers; hr = 0x80073cf2
```

`setupact.log`:

```
2017-07-21 15:12:54, Info                  SYSPRP ========================================================
2017-07-21 15:12:54, Info                  SYSPRP ===          Beginning of a new sysprep run          ===
2017-07-21 15:12:54, Info                  SYSPRP ========================================================
2017-07-21 15:12:54, Info       [0x0f004d] SYSPRP The time is now 2017-07-21 15:12:54
2017-07-21 15:12:54, Info       [0x0f004e] SYSPRP Initialized SysPrep log at C:\WINDOWS\System32\Sysprep\Panther
2017-07-21 15:12:54, Info       [0x0f0054] SYSPRP ValidatePrivileges:User has required privileges to sysprep machine
2017-07-21 15:12:54, Info       [0x0f007e] SYSPRP FCreateTagFile:Tag file C:\WINDOWS\System32\Sysprep\Sysprep_succeeded.tag does not already exist, no need to delete anything
2017-07-21 15:12:54, Info       [0x0f003d] SYSPRP WinMain:Displaying dialog box for user to choose sysprep mode...
2017-07-21 15:12:59, Info       [0x0f00d7] SYSPRP WinMain:Pre-validing 'cleanup' internal providers.
2017-07-21 15:12:59, Info                  SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:Running platform actions specified in action file for phase 3
2017-07-21 15:12:59, Info       [0x0f00ba] SYSPRP SysprepSession::CreateSession: Successfully created instance with mount path C:, action file C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Cleanup.xml, and mode <null>
2017-07-21 15:12:59, Info                  SYSPRP SysprepSession::Validate: Beginning action execution from C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Cleanup.xml
2017-07-21 15:12:59, Info                  SYSPRP ActionPlatform::GetStringValue: Getting REG_SZ value SysprepMode under key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Sysprep
2017-07-21 15:12:59, Info                  SYSPRP ActionPlatform::GetValue: Getting value SysprepMode under key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Sysprep
2017-07-21 15:12:59, Warning               SYSPRP ActionPlatform::GetValue: Error from RegQueryValueEx on value SysprepMode under key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Sysprep; dwRet = 0x2
2017-07-21 15:12:59, Info                  SYSPRP SysprepSession::CreateXPathForSelection: Sysprep mode in registry is <null>
2017-07-21 15:12:59, Info                  SYSPRP ActionPlatform::GetStringValue: Getting REG_SZ value PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE under key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
2017-07-21 15:12:59, Info                  SYSPRP ActionPlatform::GetValue: Getting value PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE under key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
2017-07-21 15:12:59, Info                  SYSPRP SysprepSession::CreateXPathForSelection: Processor architecture in registry is AMD64
2017-07-21 15:12:59, Info       [0x0f0080] SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Found 'Sysprep_Clean_Validate_Opk' in C:\Windows\System32\spopk.dll; executing it
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info       [0x0f0081] SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Successfully executed 'Sysprep_Clean_Validate_Opk' from C:\Windows\System32\spopk.dll without error
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info       [0x0f00d7] SYSPRP WinMain:Pre-validing 'generalize' internal providers.
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info                  SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:Running platform actions specified in action file for phase 1
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info       [0x0f00ba] SYSPRP SysprepSession::CreateSession: Successfully created instance with mount path C:, action file C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Generalize.xml, and mode <null>
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info                  SYSPRP SysprepSession::Validate: Beginning action execution from C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Generalize.xml
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info                  SYSPRP ActionPlatform::GetStringValue: Getting REG_SZ value SysprepMode under key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Sysprep
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info                  SYSPRP ActionPlatform::GetValue: Getting value SysprepMode under key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Sysprep
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Warning               SYSPRP ActionPlatform::GetValue: Error from RegQueryValueEx on value SysprepMode under key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\Sysprep; dwRet = 0x2
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info                  SYSPRP SysprepSession::CreateXPathForSelection: Sysprep mode in registry is <null>
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info                  SYSPRP ActionPlatform::GetStringValue: Getting REG_SZ value PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE under key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info                  SYSPRP ActionPlatform::GetValue: Getting value PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE under key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info                  SYSPRP SysprepSession::CreateXPathForSelection: Processor architecture in registry is AMD64
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info       [0x0f0080] SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Found 'ValidateBitLockerState' in C:\Windows\System32\BdeSysprep.dll; executing it
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info       [0x0f0081] SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Successfully executed 'ValidateBitLockerState' from C:\Windows\System32\BdeSysprep.dll without error
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info       [0x0f0080] SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Found 'SysprepGeneralizeValidate' in C:\Windows\System32\AppxSysprep.dll; executing it
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Info                  SYSPRP Entering SysprepGeneralizeValidate (Appx) - validating whether all apps are also provisioned.

2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error                 SYSPRP Package Holograms_1.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image.

2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error                 SYSPRP Failed to remove apps for the current user: 0x80073cf2.

2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error                 SYSPRP Exit code of RemoveAllApps thread was 0x3cf2.

2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error      [0x0f0082] SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Failure occurred while executing 'SysprepGeneralizeValidate' from C:\Windows\System32\AppxSysprep.dll; dwRet = 0x3cf2
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error                 SYSPRP SysprepSession::Validate: Error in validating actions from C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Generalize.xml; dwRet = 0x3cf2
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error                 SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while validating SysprepSession actions; dwRet = 0x3cf2
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error      [0x0f0070] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:An error occurred while running registry sysprep DLLs, halting sysprep execution. dwRet = 0x3cf2
2017-07-21 15:13:00, Error      [0x0f00d8] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while pre-validate sysprep generalize internal providers; hr = 0x80073cf2
2017-07-21 15:13:02, Info       [0x0f0052] SYSPRP Shutting down SysPrep log
2017-07-21 15:13:02, Info       [0x0f004d] SYSPRP The time is now 2017-07-21 15:13:02
```

Comment: This happens when you manually remove built-in packages. You would have to log in as the user who has that package installed and remove the reference to the now non-existant package. Even if you are successful in syspreping you might end up with a system that won't update. I found this after making my image and deploying the test. The final deployed computer could not run Windows update. You might want to start over.

Comment: @HackSlash  i am that user.  How would I remove the reference?  The program doesn't appear in Add/Remove Programs, and the registry keys won't delete.

Comment: by using the last two commands in that article you linked:

    `Run Remove-AppxPackage -Package Holograms_1.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy` Remove the provisioning by running the following cmdlet:
    
    `Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName Holograms_1.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy`

Comment: @HackSlash as noted above, i cannot do so because the package names do not exist and do not appear in the list: 

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-AppxPackage -Package Microsoft.Holograms_1.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy
Remove-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF1, Package was not found.
Windows cannot remove Microsoft.Holograms_1.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy because the current user does not have that
package installed.

Comment: @HackSlash also encountered: Remove-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CFA, Removal failed. Please contact your software vendor.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CFA)
error 0x80070032: AppX Deployment Remove operation on package Holograms_1.0.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy from:
C:\Windows\SystemApps\Holograms_cw5n1h2txyewy failed. This app is part of Windows and cannot be uninstalled on a
per-user basis. An administrator can attempt to remove the app from the computer using Turn Windows Features on or
off. However, it may not be possible to uninstall the app.

Comment: That has your answer. Go to: https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5023-windows-features-turn-off.html

Comment: @HackSlash `WindowsFeatures` does not contain any hologram-related checkboxes.

Comment: And this is why I recommended you start over. Open a ticket with Microsoft support because this is a bug and not a feature.

Comment: Technically not a bug due to the fact Microsoft doesn't support removing the default applications

Comment: @Ramhound it certainly is a bug; in this case it's complaining about a nonexistent default application.  I never manually removed it; i suspect it's a result of having used insider preview builds some months ago.